# Unable to (Un)Install phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

### System Specifications

- OS

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

- Apache2

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2022-06-14T12:30:21
```

- PHP

```
PHP 8.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2022 09:40:11) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

But I am also using PHP7.4 for the main domain on the server.

### Issue

**I can't open phpMyAdmin**. I get this error:

[image: Error when trying to open phpMyAdmin]

There is nothing in the log files `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or `/var/log/apache2/access.log`. I have tried removing phpMyAdmin using `apt remove phpMyAdmin` (in an attempt to reinstall it), and I get this error:

[image: Error caused by (un)installing phpMyAdmin]

The same error appears if I choose to ignore and install again.

I've tried creating the `Debian-sys-maint` user in mysql, but it doesn't work. I recently upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04 from 20... I had some issues with the root user not being able to log in through the terminal, but that is fixed. Any advice? Where should I look?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment without 50 reputation but I have the same/similar problem - this is obviously not an answer as such, but more information.

Yes, I have the same/similar problem. Upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and upgraded php from 7.4 to 8.1. Phpmyadmin was working fine before (v5.0.3 from Oct 2020) but now I get a load of errors on the login page

```
Deprecation Notice in ./vendor/twig/twig/src/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php#40
 realpath(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($path) of type string is deprecated
```

which looks like its barfing at php8.1, and then if I try to login I get the same as above with "The page not working right now"

When I run `sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin` it reports "Package phpmyadmin is not installed, so not removed" which is unhelpful as it is still installed and exists in /usr/share/phpmyadmin and the apache2 config file is enabled.

So how does one remove it - will simply deleting the /usr/share/phpmyadmin folder and disabling the phpmyadmin.conf in apache2 to work, or will it leave other stuff behind that will mess up a re-install with the latest version?

Or can I simply install the latest version over the top of the existing 5.0.3?